# Weird indexOutOfBound erro from Netty's ChannelBuffer.read?

Tags: java, nio, netty

I have the following simple code in my netty project, it expects to read an integer from the upstream. No encoder is in the pipeline.

```
public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) throws Exception {
        ChannelBuffer m = (ChannelBuffer) e.getMessage();

        m.readInt() 
    }
```

When the data comes in from the network the method is fired correctly (good sign) but when attempting to read, it gives the following error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at org.jboss.netty.buffer.AbstractChannelBuffer.checkReadableBytes(AbstractChannelBuffer.java:657)
    at org.jboss.netty.buffer.AbstractChannelBuffer.readInt(AbstractChannelBuffer.java:272)
    at PushServer.Netty.PushClientHandler.messageReceived(PushClientHandler.java:33)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:274)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:261)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:349)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.processSelectedKeys(NioWorker.java:281)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:201)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.IoWorkerRunnable.run(IoWorkerRunnable.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:637)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you don't have a decoder in your pipeline?  Even if your peer wrote 4 bytes, you might get less than 4 bytes, and therefore there is high chance of getting an IOOBE.   Actually, [a section in the official user guide](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/guide/html/start.html#d0e794) explains exactly same case.